# Brazilian trying to obtain my flight history from 2000 to the present

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, history

The US Consulate has twice denied my application for a new B-2 visa, alleging that I overstayed my I-94 in April 2001. They refuse to present documentation proving that this is the case. I did not overstay! Immigration did not stamp my passport upon departure from the US. It has been 22 years, and I do not have ticket stubs, etc. How can I obtain my travel history from 22 years ago? CBP only goes back 10 years online.

Comment: You mean I-94, right?

Comment: There is no exit passport control in the US, so there are indeed never any exit stamps. Do you have stamps from other countries? Do you have bank or card statements from back then? Flight or hotel booking confirmation e-mails? Frequent flyer statements? I’m surprised they have history going back that far…

Comment: What kind of visa did you use back then? Do you still have that visa?

Comment: Oops, I meant an I-94, which was good for 6 months. The visa issued in 2000 was a B-2 good for 10 years. I still have it as is glued inside my passport. I have only traveled internationally twice: once to the USA in 10/2000 (I was stamped out of Brazil), and to Portugal in 01/2002 returning to Brazil in 02/2002 (I was stamped into and out of Portugal). No bank statements etc. as dates 22 years ago!

Comment: When did you leave the US? Do you have any pictures with identifiable locations from back then? Any activities you attended?

Comment: I left approximately 2 days before my I-94 expired, which was April 4, 2001. I don't have anything that proves that I left before April 4, 2001. It's my word against the consulate, thus I need proof from CBP or similar agency demonstrating I indeed left on an exact date. I've contacted 3 agencies so far and none have anything. Thx for the help!

Comment: You didn't get an entry stamp from whichever country you flew to upon your departure from the US? You can also send a Freedom of Information Act (FOIA) request to CBP for this info. https://www.foia.gov/?id=33a1c54c-5548-4917-9575-bbf66fb4b524&type=component enter Customs and Border Protection in the "Agency" field and submit the request. Though I suspect that is what the consulate sees, so it would only confirm their POV

Comment: Thanks for comment! Brazil does not do entry stamps for Brazilians, unfortunately. I had already received a reply from FOIA as you suggested. They have no record of my leaving the USA in 2001 or at any time :-( I just wish I could find what the Consulate sees.

Answer (score 1):

When you left the US , the airline should have collected your I-94 and submitted it to the CBP. That apparently didn't happen, but from your post it's hard to tell what exactly happened to your I-94. Could be that airline didn't collect it, that the airline misplaced it, that you just took it home with you, etc.

Check out some advice no how to proceed for a few different scenarios.

https://www.immihelp.com/returning-uncollected-i94-form-to-cbp/

You will have to dig up some proof that you actually left the US. The link gives a few examples of what might work there.

Comment: Thanks so much! The airline did not collect my I-94. I still have it together with old my passport. The link to immihelp is excellent. Lots of good info there! Obrigada!!